# Solving for $x$, ${\sqrt{7x-5}} - {\sqrt{2x}} = {\sqrt{15 - 7x}}$

Tags: roots

could I please have some help solving this equation for $x$ ?

${\sqrt{7x-5}} - {\sqrt{2x}} = {\sqrt{15 - 7x}}$

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. Consider adding some context to your problems to improve your chances of a good response.

Comment: ok, then I get,

Comment: The range of possible values of $x$ is very limited. Identify it first and you will find a nice simple solution for the equation (inspection could help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$${\sqrt{7x-5}} - {\sqrt{2x}} = {\sqrt{15 - 7x}}$$
$$7x-5 - 2{\sqrt{2x(7x-5)}}+2x =15 - 7x$$
$$16x-20 =2{\sqrt{2x(7x-5)}}$$
$$8x-10 ={\sqrt{2x(7x-5)}}$$
$$64x^2-160x+100=14x^2-10x$$
$$50x^2-150x+100=0$$
$$x^2-3x+2=0$$
$$x=1,x=2$$
only $x=2$ is solution

Comment: ohhhhh, ok, thank you very much, I was expanding the root in line 3 not dividing it by 2, thank you!

Comment: So $x$ = 1 or 2

Comment: +1 however a discussion on the correctness of the solutions found is probably called for.. I mean if the last equation has a negative solution is clear that it is not a solution to our original problem ;-)

Comment: @PlsHelpMe It is customary to accept answers that are most helpful to you. Do you have any reason not to accept this answer?